# Overlay above flyout

Tags: uwp, z-index, flyout

I've got a flyout, and when the user changes data on it, I want to make it completely unreachable while the content is loading. I've achieved this with other controls by having a grid with a ProgressRing at the highest point in the Z-Index that I show before loading data and hide after.

The issue is that the flyout renders above everything else, which makes it still accessible. Even setting the "IsEnabled" property of the page to "False" allows the controls within it to stay visible.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

What it looks like:
[image]

*(The Combobox is interactive)*

What it should look like:
[image]

*(The ComboBox isn't interactive)*

Any ideas on how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but you can try with *IsHitTestVisible* and *Opacity* properties of you flyout's content. I've made a simple example how it may work - page's XAML:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:NullableToBool x:Key="NullConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="400" Height="200">
    <ProgressRing Width="100" Height="100" Margin="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible"
                  IsActive="{x:Bind TheButton.IsChecked, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource NullConverter}}"/>
    <Button Content="Show flyout" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout>
                <Border Background="Gray" IsHitTestVisible="{x:Bind IsActive, Mode=OneWay}" Opacity="{x:Bind FlyoutOpacity, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <ToggleButton Margin="20" x:Name="TheButton" IsChecked="False" Click="TheButton_Click" Content="Doing smth" Width="100"/>
                </Border>
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

and the code behind:

```cs
public class NullableToBool : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is bool ? (bool)value : false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaiseProperty(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    private bool isActive = true;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return isActive; }
        set { isActive = value; RaiseProperty(nameof(IsActive)); }
    }

    private double flyoutOpacity = 1.0;
    public double FlyoutOpacity
    {
        get { return flyoutOpacity; }
        set { flyoutOpacity = value; RaiseProperty(nameof(FlyoutOpacity)); }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void TheButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsActive = false;
        FlyoutOpacity = 0.1;
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        IsActive = true;
        FlyoutOpacity = 1.0;
        (sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to block the UI while the ProgressRing showing. You could use the [ModalDialog](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Controls#modaldialog) in Template10.

> Almost every app has the need to display some form of a Modal Dialog - a UI element that blocks interaction with the rest of an application until either the user has dismissed it or some application task has completed.